# remove directory structure when zipping files in PHP

Tags: php, directory, zip

I have run into a bit of a problem when zipping files in PHP. I have a function which zips an array of files, these files are all in different directories. The function looks like :

```
function create_zip($files = array(),$destination = '',$overwrite = false,$add_to_db=true) {
    print_r($files);
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        if($zip->open($destination,$overwrite ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {
            return false;
        }
        for($i=0;$i < count($files); $i++) {
            //echo $files[$i].'<br>';
            $zip->addFile($files[$i],$files[$i]);
        }



        $zip->close();

        if(file_exists($destination)) {
       //  echo("Success");
       if($add_to_db == true) { add_file($destination); }

            return true;

        } else {
        //echo("Failed");
           return false;
        }
    }
```

When a user downloads and extracts the zip the structure of files is like :

```
folder/folder2/file1.jpg
folder/file2.jpg
folder/folder2/folder3/file3.jpg
```

My question is, is it possible to have PHP place all the files in the root of the zip and ignore the given structure. So the extracted files would look like:

```
/file1.jpg
/file2.jpg
/file3.jpg
```

The only solution I could think of was moving all the files into a folder and then zipping this folder, but this seemed like overkill.

Answer (score 3):

Specify just a filename (no path) for the 2nd parameter to `addFile()`:

```
$zip->addFile( $files[$i], basename($files[$i]) );
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php

Be aware that if you attempt to add multiple files with the same basename (e.g. `folder1/foo.jpg` and `folder2/foo.jpg`), you'll overwrite the first one and only the second one will end up in the zip file.